# Autowiring issue in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to implement Kafka with Spring Cloud Stream. I followed instructions from the official [website](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) and developed a [project](https://github.com/pavankjadda/SpringCloudStream-KafkaStreams). When I run the project in IntelliJ, I got following error

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.kafkastreams.service.GreetingsSender required a bean of type 'com.kafkastreams.stream.GreetingsStreams' that could not be found.
```

I am not sure where I did wrong, Any help would be really appreciated. Code uploaded to [GitHub](https://github.com/pavankjadda/SpringCloudStream-KafkaStreams) for reference.

Comment: Shouldn't your `GreetingsConfig` be a `class` and not an `interface`?

Comment: You are right, it should be class. Man, I was dumb, thought it was something to do with configuration. Please post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GreetingsConfig` should be a `class` instead of an `interface`

```
@EnableBinding(GreetingsStreams.class)
public class GreetingsConfig
{

}
```